# Edit document text woes

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF file, I would like to remove some text. I am using Adobe Acrobat X Pro.

I chose
<kbd>Tools</kbd>

<kbd>Recognize Text</kbd>


<kbd>ClearScan</kbd>

Then I choose

<kbd>Tools</kbd>


<kbd>Content</kbd>


<kbd>Edit Document Text</kbd>

However when I try to edit the text I get this message

> All or part of the selection has no available system font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just redacting the text.

[Guide to using Redaction in Acrobat](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2010/06/ricks-guide-to-using-redaction-in-acrobat-x-pro)